# Sony camera API. Settings to use?

Tags: camera, sony

Good day,

I was just wondering to which settings the camera should be set when I want to connect from my Windows 7 PC to my camera over Wi-Fi.

I'm using the DSC-HX60V. I can connect via the Sony app from my android device when the camera is set to application type "Smart Remote Embedded".

Now to which mode should the camera be set when I want to connect over Wi-Fi?

Or can the camera simply be connected to a Wi-Fi AP and that's all that is needed?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To access Camera Remote API, please start the the PlayMemories Camera Apps "Smart Remote Control" application in the camera.

Best Regards,
Prem, Developer World team